# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\petrol_pump\add_customer.php on line 219

Tags: php, mysql

i got this error on some specific pc's but when i run this program on another pc it will work 100% properly
 i run this code on various system but some system give errors.
so any one can help me

please

in advance thank you

```
<?php include('common/header.php');
$test=$_GET['id'];
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$user_data=$db->SelectSingle("customer_details","cust_id=".$_GET['id'],"","");
}
}

$state=$db->SelectTable("state","","");
?> 
<form class="form-horizontal" action="add_customerins.php" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                            <div class="span5">
                          <legend>Customer Details</legend>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Customer Name :</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-large" name="cust_name" id="cust_name" value="<?=$user_data['customer_name'];?>" placeholder="Customer Name">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Customer Address :</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <textarea class="span11" rows="3" name="cust_adr" id="cust_adr"><?=$user_data['customer_address'];?></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Customer E-mail :</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                             <div class="input-prepend">
                                <span class="add-on">@</span><input type="text" value="<?=$user_data['customer_email'];?>" name="cust_email" id="cust_email" placeholder="Email Address" class=" ">
                             </div>
                          </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Alternate E-mail :</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                             <div class="input-prepend">
                                <span class="add-on">@</span><input type="text" value="<?=$user_data['cust_alt_email'];?>" name="alt_email" id="alt_email" placeholder="Alternate Email Address" class=" ">
                             </div>
                          </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Customer Phone No. :</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-large" value="<?=$user_data['cust_phone'];?>" name="cust_ph" id="cust_ph" placeholder="Phone No">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Alternate Phone No. :</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-large" value="<?=$user_data['cust_alt_phone'];?>" name="alt_ph" id="alt_ph" placeholder="Alternate Phone No">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">State :</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                <select tabindex="1" class="span8" name="cust_st" id="cust_st" >
                                    <option value="">Select State</option>
                                    <?php if(count($state)>0){
                                    foreach($state as $stat)
                                    { ?>
                                    <option value="<?=$stat['stid'];?>"<?php if($stat['stid']==$user_data['state_id']){ echo "selected";}?>><?=$stat['state_name'];?></option>
                                    <?
                                    } }
                                    ?>
                             </select>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Pincode :</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-large" value="<?=$user_data['pincode'];?>" name="cust_pin" id="cust_pin" placeholder="Pincode">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span5">
                <!-- BEGIN SAMPLE FORMPORTLET-->
                 <legend>Customer Tax Details</legend>
                        <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">VAT No. :</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-large" value="<?=$user_data['cust_vat'];?>" name="vat_no" id="vat_no" placeholder="VAT No">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">TIN No. :</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="input-large" value="<?=$user_data['cust_tin'];?>" name="tin_no" id="tin_no" placeholder="TIN No">

                                </div>
                            </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<div align="center">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save" /> 
<input type="reset" name="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Reset" />    
</div>

<input name="cstid" type="hidden"  value="<?=$test;?>" />
<input name="MM_up_insert" type="hidden"          value="insert_up"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You really should share the code in question. Gives folks at least a chance of helping out.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace **`}`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i stated in the comments, you're missing a closing brace (**`}`**).

This is the block of code that is causing the issue:

```
<?php
if (count($state) > 0) {
    foreach ($state as $stat) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?= $stat['stid']; ?>"<?php
        if ($stat['stid'] == $user_data['state_id']) {
            echo "selected";
        }
        ?>><?= $stat['state_name']; ?></option>
<?
} }
?>
```

Notice that last bit?

```
<?
} }
?>
```

You're using php short tags and you probably don't have them enabled.
Change that to this:

```
<?php
} }
?>
```

And that should fix your error